# How does the power function work

Tags: prolog

This is My First Logic Programming Language course so this is a really Dumb Question But I cannot for the life of me figure out how does this power predicate work I've tried making a search tree to trace it But I still cannot understand how is it working

```
mult(_ , 0 ,0).
mult(X , Y, Z):-
   Y > 0,
   Y1 is Y - 1,
   mult(X,Y1,Z1),
   Z is Z1 + X.
exp2(_ ,0 , 1).
exp2(X,Y,Z):-
         Y > 0,
         Y1 is Y - 1,
         exp2(X , Y1 , Z1),
         mult(X,Z1,Z).
```

I so far get that I'm going to call the exp2 predicate till I reach the point where the Y is going to be Zero then I'm going to start multiplying from there, but At the last call when it's at exp2(2 , 1 , Z) what is the Z value and how does the predicate work from there?

Thank you very much =)

EDIT: I'm really sorry for the Late reply I had some problems and couldn't access my PC

Comment: First step, before trying to understand how they work, do you know what `mult/3` *does*, and what `exp2/3` *does*?

Comment: sadly no but I've seen the mult/3 as an error quite alot But the professor hasn't mentioned it

Comment: You might experiment with some values to see what each does. `exp2(X, Y, Z)` *probably* computes `X` to the power of `Y` giving `Z`. `mult/3` is not clear on the surface, so you have to try things. Try trivial cases and walk through the code to figure out what it's doing. Probably easiest to start with trying to understand `mult` since it only calls itself. Then move on to understanding `exp2`.

Comment: OK here's a hint, which I figured out in a few seconds just by playing with these predicates in a Prolog prompt. `mult(X, Y, Z)` multiplies `X` by `Y` giving `Z`. And `exp2` takes `X` to the `Y` power giving `Z`. How do they work? Broadly speaking (and by inspecting the code), `mult` multiplies two numbers by successive additions. `exp2` is similar in that it performs exponentiation by successive multiplications. They are basically the same algorithm.

Comment: Read the predicates as rules. `mult(_, 0, 0)` says that *any number times 0 is 0*. And `mult(X, Y, Z)` says *`Z` is the result of multiplying `X` times `Y` **if** `Y` is greater than 0, and `Y1` is one less than `Y`, and..., etc*.

Comment: Do you know Python or other non-logic language? I wanted to write a Python equivalent, but don't know if it would actually help. :-)

Comment: @lurker I kind of get what you're saying but I still don't understand what is the /3 in the "mult/3" Is it an arithmetic operation Or An error? I've only seen it In errors honestly So I'm really confused

Comment: @Evgeny I know Java, as far as i took python it was only while loops So I''m not sure if I would understand certain syntax :(

Comment: `mult/3` is short-hand to say that `mult` with *arity* of 3, as in it takes 3 arguments. If you had a `mult` with 2 arguments, it would be `mult/2`.

Comment: @Sorata Sure, edited the answer adding Java code :-)

Comment: Do either of the answers help? Or is the question still unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

I'll walk through `mult/3` in more detail here, but I'll leave `exp2/3` to you as an exercise. It's similar..

As I mentioned in my comment, you want to read a Prolog predicate as a rule.

```
mult(_ , 0 ,0).
```

This rule says *0 is the result of multiplying anything (`_`) by 0*. The variable `_` is an *anonymous* variable, meaning it is not only a variable, but you don't care what its value is.

```
mult(X, Y, Z) :-
```

This says, *`Z` is the result of multiplying `X` by `Y` **if**...*.

```
   Y > 0,
```

Establish that `Y` is greater than 0.

```
   Y1 is Y - 1,
```

And that `Y1` has the value of `Y` minus 1.

```
   mult(X, Y1, Z1),
```

And that `Z1` is the result of multiplying `X` by `Y1`.

```
   Z is Z1 + X.
```

And `Z` is the value of `Z1` plus `X`.

Or reading the `mult(X, Y, Z)` rule altogether:

> *`Z` is the result of multiplying `X` by `Y` **if** `Y` is greater than 0, and `Y1` is `Y-1`, and `Z1` is the result of multiplying `X` by `Y1`, and `Z` is the result of adding `Z1` to `X`*.

Now digging a little deeper, you can see this is a *recursive* definition, as in the multiplication of two numbers is being defined by another multiplication. But *what* is being multiplied is important. Mathematically, it's using the fact that `x * y` is equal to `x * (y - 1) + x`. So it keeps reducing the second multiplicand by 1 and calling itself on the slightly reduced problem. When does this recursive reduction finally end? Well, as shown above, the second rule says `Y` must be greater than 0. If `Y` is 0, then the first rule, `mult(_, 0, 0)` applies and the recursion finally comes back with a 0.

If you are not sure how *recursion* works or are unfamiliar with it, I highly recommend Googling it to understand it. That is, indeed, a concept that applies to many computer languages. But you need to be careful about learning Prolog via comparison with other languages. Prolog is fundamentally different in it's behavior from procedural/imperative languages like Java, Python, C, C++, etc. It's best to get used to interpreting Prolog *rules* and *facts* as I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to compute 2^3 as assign result to R.
For that you will call exp2(2, 3, R).
It will recursively call exp2(2, 2, R1) and then exp2(2, 1, R2) and finally exp(2, 0, R3).

At this point exp(_, 0, 1) will match and R3 will be assigned to 1.

Then when call stack unfolds 1 will be multiplied by 2 three times.

In Java this logic would be encoded as follows. Execution would go pretty much the same route.

```
  public static int Exp2(int X, int Y) {
    if (Y == 0) { // exp2(_, 0, 1).
      return 1;
    }
    if (Y > 0) { // Y > 0
      int Y1 = Y - 1;  // Y1 is Y - 1
      int Z1 = Exp2(X, Y1);  // exp2(X, Y1, Z1);
      return X * Z1;  // mult(X, Z1, Z).
    }
    return -1;  // this should never happen.
  }
```